# RecyclerView LAG occurs the first time & first 5-6 items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I read too many articles about this. I Tried all type of permutation & combination of recyclerview method such as `setHasFixedSize(true)` ,`setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`, `setItemViewCacheSize(20)` etc. But my prediction is the below statement is ture:

**The main reason Jank occurs the first time because on the first time it is loading the values onto memory dynamically. while once it is down it already has a few elements pre loaded**

1. When I run my app on android the first time I can see a first scroll is lagging(`exactly 5-6 items`).Once that first scroll is done the list view is really really fast, I mean faster than anything else.
2. If I `close my app without killing it from background` and open it again, It won't lag.
3. if I "kill" my app and run it again, I get the lag for first 5-6 items.

**MY QUESTIONS :**

1. Is there any way to `load the values onto memory dynamically before user interaction, Like showing a splash screen and load the layout in background thread`? I have tried splash screen but this question is how to load the layout onto memory.
2. How is the scrolling of youTube,Twitter,Instagram is smooth? How are they load their layout first time onto memory?

**Note:** Main container is `ConstraintLayout with custom background` & my hierarchy is totally flat, but 3 buttons have `drawable icons` and `custom background` , `one material shapable imageview`, one slider with `custom thumb and custom progress drawable` and a `frameLayout`

Comment: Make sure to override `getItemType` `getItemId` and `getItemCount` properly and use `setHasStableIds(true)`

Comment: @cmak when I'm using ```setHasStableIds(true)``` item positions are changing when I scroll to the top & I have never tried getItemType & getItemId ,could you provide some code sample or tutorial please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to override:

- `getItemViewType(…)` from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int)):

> Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view
> recycling.
>
> The default implementation of this method returns 0, making the
> assumption of a single view type for the adapter. Unlike ListView
> adapters, types need not be contiguous. Consider using id resources to
> uniquely identify item view types.

If you have different view types, return an `int` that identifies said view types, otherwise no need to override.

- `getItemId(…)` from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemId(int)):

> Return the stable ID for the item at position. If hasStableIds would
> return false this method should return NO_ID. The default
> implementation of this method returns NO_ID.

That means the function must return a unique id for every item. Use the id of your objects if there's any, otherwise try with the hashCode:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
}
```

If implemented properly, use `setHasStableIds(true)`. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#setHasStableIds(boolean)):

> Indicates whether each item in the data set can be represented with a
> unique identifier of type java.lang.Long.

- `getItemCount(…)` from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemCount()):

> Returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter.

Simply the number of items in the list.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but no change , but I found my issue , I'm using ```4 shape drawable,4 vector drawable & 3 custom styles```. I can clearly see that when I'm using drawable it is lagging but after removing drawable it is fine & super fast. Could you help me in this case? Note: I need all drawable for my design.

Comment: Have you added support verctor drawable option?

Comment: I don't know what is that, sorry I'm beginner

Comment: @coderror I'm talking about this https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution It's hard to help without any code, it could be the device you tested it in, could be your binding methods, etc